# Ошибка OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте

Tags: python, сокет, ос

Выдаёт ошибку:

> OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на
> объекте, не являющемся сокетом

если что в `regdata.txt` хранится "`username password`"

```
import os
import socket

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 12345

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host,port))

file = open("regdata.txt", "r")
userdata = file.read()

while True:
    if not userdata == "":
        s.sendall(userdata.encode('utf-8'))
        file.close()
        data = s.recv(1024)
        s.close()
        print('Received:', repr(data))
    else:
        os.startfile("reg.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

Я решил ошибку убрав:

```py
while True:
```